# android: how to only record specific app voice

Tags: android

I try this [screen and voice recorder](https://github.com/Truiton/ScreenCapture), but i find it record all voices include my home environment noise, so how to only record phone voice without these noise

[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFiUlpXAu4E&feature=youtu.be) is sample app result video with noise(the noise is dadadadada)

Comment: What is "phone voice"?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I mean voice in recorded video